# Creating new tile cache using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, cache, tilecache

I'm struggling to understand how to create a tile cache using ArcGIS Pro. Every time I try, it creates an empty map service.

I'm caching a small scale just to test it out (it takes about 3 minutes for the publishing tool to complete). In the service editor I have the options "Using tiles from a new cache" and "Cache automatically on the server" turned on. I also chose an area of interest. I have "auto-suggest" set for the tiling scheme, it notes "Using" and lists they layer's projection. I then view the job status and it says "Publish status: Succeeded. Cache status: Succeeded." When I go to ArcGIS Server Manager, I see the map service there, with the thumbnail showing the appropriate layer, but when I click on the thumbnail to view that layer, nothing is there. When I go to the arcgiscache folder, I see the cached scale and it's populated with an RC#### bundle file. In manager, the service is pointing at the correct cache folder so I don't see a reason why it's not pulling from there. When I click on the cache status (the little four squares next to the name of the map service), it says 100% of the tiles are available. When I go to my rest services page, I can click down into the map service and find the scale at which I tiled; I click on "Start tile" and it says 404 Not Found, so it's not finding the tiles.

I've tried to create the cache manually too. It never works.

What am I missing?

Comment: May not be the issue, but make sure you have the layer visibility turned on in ArcPro when you do your caching, I discovered that it creates a blank output if turned off, nuts!

Comment: @Hornbydd - thanks for the information, but sadly that's not the answer for me. Do you have a tiled service easily accessible from your browser rest services? Could you tell me what you see if you click on the map service and then under Tile Info, click one of the "Start Tile" links for a scale at which you have cached? I'm wondering if you get a 404 error or if there's something in there. 

I've also noticed that it has every scale possible listed under Tile Info, but I only selected to cache at 3 of those scales so I'm not sure why it shows every scale. Perhaps that's normal...

Answer (score 0):

Had some issues creating cached tile services as well. After publishing successfully, the service doesn't show when dragged to the map. To overcome this, I used the tool: Manage Map Service Cache Tiles (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/server/manage-map-server-cache-tiles.htm) to recreate the tiles. Once the tool ran, I was able to see my tiles properly.